# Cancel opposite terms, and only that

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following problem: I have a formula which looks like
$$A = \sum \frac{1}{p_1 p_2 p_3 \dots},$$
where the $p_i$ are linear expression in some variables X.
In the sum there are many opposite terms, such as
$$\frac{1}{(a-b)} + \frac{1}{-a+b}+ \dots,$$
and I would like mathematica to recognise this fact and cancel them. However, I want mathematica to do ONLY this, nothing more.
The problem is that if I use Simplify, mathematica will do more than that: it will try to put everything together, i.e. it will find the (foreboding) polynomials such that
$$ A = \frac{P}{Q}.$$
If I don't do anything, instead, mathematica will not recognise the cancellations: even just
$$\frac{1}{(a-b)} + \frac{1}{-a+b},$$
does not get simplified automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little risky to suggest a solution without a concrete example to test it on first, but see if this does approximately what you want.

```
1/(r-s)+1/(a-b)+1/(-t+u)+1/(-a+b)+1/(-m+n)+1/(c-d)+1/(-c+d)//. 1/(a_-b_)+1/(-a_+b_)->0
```

which returns

```
(* 1/(-m+n)+1/(r-s)+1/(-t+u) *)
```

It may be much more difficult to get Mathematica to do "ONLY this, nothing more."

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight modification of the Bill's approach:

```
expr = 1/(a - b) + 1/(-a + b) + 1/(2 a + 3 b) + 1/(a + 2 b)
(*1/(a - b) + 1/(-a + b) + 1/(a + 2 b) + 1/(2 a + 3 b)*)
expr //. x_ + y_ /; Simplify[x + y == 0] -> 0
(*1/(a + 2 b) + 1/(2 a + 3 b)*)
```

In its most general form it is not very efficient, but you can adjust the pattern, e.g.

```
expr //. x_Power + y_Power /; Simplify[x + y == 0] -> 0
(*1/(a + 2 b) + 1/(2 a + 3 b)*)
```

or

```
expr //. 1/x_ + 1/y_ /; Simplify[x + y == 0] -> 0
(*1/(a + 2 b) + 1/(2 a + 3 b)*)
```